# 'Publish failed' for deploying new Zip Files to Azure Linux Functions App (restart required before this works)

Tags: azure, terraform, serverless

I have to restart my Azure Linux Functions App before I can redeploy using Zip File deploys. I have read that this is due to file locks, but the fixes I've attempted to use do not work. Hopefully someone from the Azure Functions team sees this and can assist.

I use the Terraform CDK to do this deployment:

```
    ...
    this.servicePlan = new ServicePlan(this, 'sp', {
      name: 'my-app',
      location: 'eastus',
      resourceGroupName: 'some-resource-group',
      osType: 'Linux',
      skuName: 'EP1', // have tried other plans such as 'EP1', 'EP3' etc.
    });

    new LinuxFunctionApp(this, 'lfa', {
      dependsOn: [
        this.servicePlan,
        this.applicationInsights,
        this.storageAccount,
      ],

      name: 'my-app',
      location: 'eastus',
      resourceGroupName: 'some-resource-group',
      servicePlanId: this.servicePlan.id,
      storageAccountName: this.storageAccount.name,
      storageAccountAccessKey: this.storageAccount.primaryAccessKey,
      functionsExtensionVersion: '~4',
      httpsOnly: true,
      zipDeployFile: 'path/to/package.zip',

      appSettings: {
        AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: this.azureStorageConnectionString.value,
        FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: 'node',
        MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES: '1', // this does not fix it!
        WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE: '0', // this does not fix it!
        SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT: 'true',
        AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags: 'EnableWorkerIndexing',
        WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE: 'false',
      },

      siteConfig: {
        applicationInsightsConnectionString: this.applicationInsights.connectionString,
        applicationInsightsKey: this.applicationInsights.instrumentationKey,
        applicationStack: {
          nodeVersion: '18',
        },
        alwaysOn: false,
        elasticInstanceMinimum: 1,
        healthCheckPath: '/api/health',
        appCommandLine: 'node dist/index.js',
      },
    });
```